# If I install GLX-Dock on Ubuntu 11.10 does it replace the Unity launch bar?

Tags: software-recommendation, launcher, package-management

I want to install GLX-dock on Ubuntu 11.10. I want to know if there will be any changes to the default Unity launch bar ?
I dont want to replace anything rather want to add a dock bar at the bottom. Currently I have tint2 installed. Do i need to remove it ?

Comment: Don't worry!, installing Glx dock won't remove or change unity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh yes ! GLX Doc made no Harm to my Desktop. Here is a Screenshot of what I achieved.

[image][image]
[image]